# I am getting a 404 error when using login_required

Tags: python, django, decorator, login-required

I'm new to Django and I'm trying to make a learning log website.

When I try to restrict my topics with login_required function I get a 404 error.

Here is my code:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required   

@login_required(login_url='/users/login/')
def topics(request):
""" Show all topics."""
topics = Topic.objects.order_by("date_added")
context = {"topics": topics}
return render(request, "learning_logs/topics.html", context)
```

I get this error whenever I use the decorator in my code:

```
Using the URLconf defined in learning_log.urls, Django tried these URL 
patterns, in this order:

admin/
users/ login [name='login']
users/ logout [name='logout']
users/ registration [name='register']
learning_logs/¨

The current path, users/login/, didn't match any of these.
```

The url works fine but when I use the decorator it breaks.

Comment: Can you post your `urls.py`?

Comment: The problem is solved now. I forgott a trailing slash at the end of my url. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @noob_coder pls mark this question as solved! There is a correct answer below from Nikolas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that means you have not defined the django builtin login in your url  to solve it you can just past that inside you urls.py

```
##urls.py
    from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
    urlpatterns = [
        path('users/login/', auth_views.login, name='login'),
        path('users/logout/', auth_views.logout, name='logout'),
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    ]
```

> if you have already done that you need to do the following in views

```
##views.py
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required   

@login_required(login_url=reverse_lazy("login"))
def topics(request):
""" Show all topics."""
topics = Topic.objects.order_by("date_added")
context = {"topics": topics}
return render(request, "learning_logs/topics.html", context)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `users` urls don't have trailing slashes. Make sure that the URLS in your `users/urls.py` end with slashes. For example:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', LoginView.as_view(), name='login')
]
```